# htaccess match all words until last slash and redirect 301

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, apache2, regex

I'm trying to escape everything until the last slash, even if there's a slash in between.
Example:

```
/site_url/courses/cat1/cat2/subcat/coursename
```

to

```
/site_url/course/courseName
```

or

```
/site_url/course/courseName
```

How could I achieve this with Nginx or Apache?

Comment: "escape everything" - It looks like you want to _remove_ everything? Is `site_url` not necessarily the same in the source/target? Although your example also appears to be capitalising the `n` in `coursename`?! "to `/site_url/course/courseName` or ..."  - Your 2 _alternatives_ appear to be the same? Do you have any other directives in your Apache `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "escape", you mean "remove" (as in your example) then you can do something like the following in your Apache config (or `.htaccess`) file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(?!/site_url/course/).+/([^/.]+)$ /site_url/course/$1
```

The *negative lookahead* (ie. `(?!/site_url/course/)`) ensures that the redirected request is not also redirected (which would cause a redirect-loop).

This is assuming you are not already using mod_rewrite.

And this obviously doesn't do anything to capitalise any letters, since your example appears to go from `/coursename` to `/courseName`, which is not a discernable *pattern* (unless this is literal text?!).

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.